# 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Tags: python, numpy, sqrt

I am trying to obtain the gumbel_r of this input list using gumbel_r.fit() and gumbel_r.ppf()

```
contoh1 = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',header=None,sheet_name='Sheet7'
dn=contoh1.columns
y1 =contoh1[dn[1]][37:43]
y2 =contoh1[dn[2]][21:43]
y3 =contoh1[dn[3]][21:43]
y4 =contoh1[dn[4]][1:43]
y5 =contoh1[dn[5]][22:44]
gmb=[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]
```

To obtain that output I used the code (it goes through a loop)

```
ch_res={}
parameter_9={}
Rx_9={}
Fx_9 = 0.5

for i in range (len(gmb)):
     ch_res[i] = np.array(gmb,dtype=object)
     parameter_9[i]= gumbel_r.fit(ch_res[i])
     Rx_9[i]= gumbel_r.ppf(Fx_9,*parameter_9[i])
```

but i got the attribute error when i run parameter_9[i] it says 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'. please help me what should i do about the code

Comment: Math on object dtype arrays is done iteratively (at python speeds), using methods of the objects themselves.  Here it's asking each object to use its own `sqrt` method.  Objects that have such a method are rare.  Operators like plus often work, but functions like `sin` or `exp` don't.

Answer (score 0):

Not all functions in SciPy are designed to handle `object` arrays.  Instead of creating `object` arrays to pass to `gumbel_r.fit()`, create arrays of `numpy.float64`.  Change this line:

```
     ch_res[i] = np.array(gmb,dtype=object)
```

to

```
     ch_res[i] = np.array(gmb, dtype=np.float64)
```

Actually, I think that should be

```
     ch_res[i] = np.array(gmb[i], dtype=np.float64)
```